# "nothing new to" VS "nothing new for"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Mechanical rock-cutting systems are certainly nothing new **to** us.
> 2. Mechanical rock-cutting systems are certainly nothing new **for** us

Which preposition is proper?
Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native English speaker I do use them differently.

When talking about a single situation or thing, I would use "*new **to** me*".

For example:

> This software might be new **to** you, but not **to** me.

This is because when you are introduced to something unique, it can only ever be new once. As another example, you might be introduced *to* somebody. The moment you are introduced, you may not know them well but you cannot be "introduced to" that person again.

I would use "new *for*....." when speaking about something *ongoing*, such as a routine.

Example:

> This is a new routine for me.

Sure, something that is "new" will eventually cease to be - but with something like a routine that is repeated you may well actually be *doing* it for some time and it still feels "new" as you are not yet used to it.